# How to configure git-duet for Intellij idea?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We are using git-duet for commit as pair as we are adopting Pair Programming Methodology.

We are using git-duet to do that.

Which is used from:
https://github.com/git-duet/git-duet

We would like to know whether Intellij Idea have support for duet commit?

If yes , How to do that?

Comment: RubyMine is based off of IntelliJ.  You *might* be able to find some guidance down there.

Comment: Please check "RubyMine integration" section from git-duet readme. It should work the same way in IDEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find directions setting up RubyMine / IntelliJ Idea with Git Duet here:
https://github.com/git-duet/git-duet#rubymine-integration

Comment: Please don't add link only answers. Plese try to add some description to it.